Transform and plot individual grouped values into (almost) full circles in `plotly` 3D spiral
I'm trying (but failing) to plot individual data points, in column prop, as a full circles (when looked at from above) in a plotly 3D spiral (see Data below). My idea was to repeat the prop values by 10 so as to have enough points to draw the circle around, but the resulting plot is far from what I'd like to get -- a 3D spiral where every prop value grouped by size and position is represented as an full circle. How can that be achieved?
data <- df %>%
  group_by(size) %>%
  slice(rep(row_number(), 10)) %>% 
  arrange(size, position) %>% 
  group_by(size, position) %>%
  mutate(
    radius = prop,
    theta = 2 * pi * position/row_number(),
    x = radius * sin(theta),
    y = radius * cos(theta)
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(z = row_number())


library(plotly)
plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z,
        type = 'scatter3d', 
        mode = 'lines',
        line = list(width = 5, color = ~size,
                    colorscale = list(c(0,'#0000FF'), c(0.5, "#00FF00"), c(1,'#FF0000'))))

EDIT:
I do have an at least initial solution here:
data <- df %>%
  group_by(size) %>%
  slice(rep(row_number(), 360)) %>%   # larger number of duplicated rows
  arrange(size, position) %>% 
  group_by(size, position) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number(),
         radius = prop,
         theta = 2 * pi * position/row,
         x = radius * sin(theta),
         y = radius * cos(theta)
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(z = consecutive_id(position))  # different conceptualization of z

And the result is much closer to what I have in mind:

What is still suboptimal are (i) the lines connecting the different z levels and (ii) the (curious) connecting lines on the circle planes. How can these types of lines be removed, rendered invisible or changed to dotted?
Data:
df <- structure(list(size = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                              5L, 5L), position = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), prop = c(0.0926574818826153, 
                                                                                                  0.110336863900613, 0.30584534522577, 0.0632319256702261, 0.0857179727070362, 
                                                                                                  0.0963964254605284, 0.269251863083524, 0.0500172581505538, 0.0706956603595971, 
                                                                                                  0.0864162665913584, 0.102858577300825, 0.288838683360005)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                            -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


data_12 <- data[data$z == 12, ], dplyr::consecutive_id() has returned consecutive id(s) but hasn't checked them for 'nearness' that could be filtered for via euclidean distance to find the 'long crossing lines' and removed.

Removing lines between levels of circles can be achieved via plot_ly(..., split = factor(data$z), d_dist <- dist(data[, 7:8], method = 'euclidean')[cumsum(1:(nrow(data)-1))];  data$dist[2:4320] <- d_dist can id longer than knn-ish lines, though chords are present also.

Looking around for another generator (x−h)^2+(y−k)^2+(z−l)^2=r^2, as the choice of rep(..., 360) fails to complete the circle(s) , whose additional benefit would likely be not having to go through the 'remove' process as data points are settled and uniformly spaced akin to sphere,

Thanks for your continued support of this question. How would you implement the new generator into the code?

I used a different calc below, and I misspoke on under sampling, but @gregor-thomas provides very nice circle_xy that addresses the final gap additionally, where r = df$prop. I'll play around with it.

Using your data and initial solution, this is merely erasure without addressing what is going on in initial solution, essentially a mechanical and repetitive operation, additionally using split to remove connector lines between circles:
remove_rows
 [1]  721  722 1441 1801 1802 2161 2162 2163 3241 3242 3601 3602 3603 3961 3962
[16] 3963 3964 

data5 <- data4[-remove_rows, ]
plot_ly(data5, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, split = factor(data5$z), 
        type = 'scatter3d', 
        mode = 'lines',
        line = list(width = 5, color = ~size,
                    colorscale = list(c(0,'#0000FF'), c(0.5, "#00FF00"), c(1,'#FF0000'))))

Color distinctions between circles are lost.

The removal and subsequent split obscures the plot order as plot on a given z starts at the connecting line from the prior z.
Levels 1,2,4,8,9 required no removal to arrive at their shape that is distinctive.
seq(1, 4320, 360) # for start rows by `z[x]` in data
 [1]    1  361  721 1081 1441 1801 2161 2521 2881 3241 3601 3961
plot(data$theta)
abline(h = 7, col = 'red')
abline(h = 6, col = 'black')


Peaks correspond to circle levels start index, z[x][1], levels 1-12 from left to right, number of points above 'red' abline correspond to number of points removed to achieve the above plot_ly, employing the split on data$z to remove connecting lines between circles.
The plot analysis and its relation to number of points to remove was arrived at after the fact, so I took a rather more empirical approach of looking at a lot of plots and asking, 'Does that look right?' As said above, Levels 1,2,4,8,9 required no removal, resulting in these removed rows.
# data$z[1-12] starting rows 
[1]    1  361  721 1081 1441 1801 2161 2521 2881 3241 3601 3961
remove_rows
 [1]  721  722 1441 1801 1802 2161 2162 2163 3241 3242 3601 3602 3603 3961 3962
[16] 3963 3964

Now, failing the 'use my data test', your approach under samples theta. Using an approach I found whose link I'll include when found again:
circles <- function(n, mu, sigma) {
    lr <- Map(rlnorm, n = n, meanlog = mu, sdlog = sigma)
    N <- length(lr)
    n <- lengths(lr, FALSE)
    data.frame(group = rep.int(gl(N, 1L), n),
               r = unlist(lr, FALSE, FALSE),
               theta = runif(sum(n), 0, 2 * pi))
} 
d <- circles(n = rep(c(500, 750, 1000),3), mu = rep(log(c(1,2,4)),3), sigma = rep(c(0.00001, 0.00001, 0.00001),3))
d$x = d$r * sin(d$theta)
d$y = d$r * cos(d$theta)
d$z = as.numeric(as.character(d$group))
plot_ly(d, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, split = factor(d$z),
type = 'scatter3d', 
        mode = 'lines',
        line = list(width = 5))


The rats nest of crossing chords that make these appear as disks can be simplified to circle perimeter rings (without gaps) using chull, then plot_ly.
Adapting circle_xy to accomodate z
circle_xyz <- function(n, r, z, close_loop = FALSE) {
theta = seq(0, 2 * pi, length.out = n + 1)
if(!close_loop) theta = theta[-(n +1)]
cbind(x = r * cos(theta), y = r * sin(theta), z = z)
}
too_many_circles <- circle_xyz(n = 4896, r = df$prop, z = 1:12, close_loop = TRUE)
Warning messages:
1: In r * cos(theta) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In r * sin(theta) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In cbind(x = r * cos(theta), y = r * sin(theta), z = z) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 3)
 too_many_df = as.data.frame(too_many_circles)
plot_ly(too_many_df, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, split = factor(too_many_df$z),
 type = 'scatter3d',
 mode = 'lines', 
 line = list(width = 5))

We have largest circles nearly closed, n is multiples of max(z), and one feels as though Zeno is arguing against arrival. So, just a few more samples closes.


Interesting. How did you identify the rows to be removed?

Added a 1:nrow idx to data. Subsetted by z, plotted both by ploty_ly and plot(data_c12$theta). A n-1 hueristic seemed to develop based on distance between initial theta results stabilizing. I'll document above and attempt removing the 'back end' after plot crosses z[x][1], likely using geos::touches. Otherwise is it a lot of looking at plots, iteratively...

Wow! Impressive! why n = 4896?

And yet 12 and friends (7,3) not closed.  How many pts added to the inscribed square yield the perceived circle (by display resolution)? d with chull above can be pushed to  circle_xyz by reducing sigma, say 0.000001, whereas circle_xyz uses equal dist between pts so additions to n reduce between pt dist (where Zeno frolics). But the arrow in flight hits its target, contrary to Zeno's argument that the arrow never arrives, at n+1. So I am curious how to derive n+1 rather than my 'add more n' above. Sounds like a question for SO, no?

The not-closed circles don't worry me. But, again, how did you arrive at n = 4896? You say "n is multiples of max(z)". max(z) translates to length(df$position), right? But how did you determine the number of multiples?

If I'd had any common sense I'd have used nrow(d) sigma 0.000001 = 6750, as my starting estimate for circle_xyz(n. 3 & 7 close at 3*(nrow(d)) = 20250, while 12 remains open, and 4 * nrow(d) = 27000, and all are (finally) closed. So, my n should have been somewhere between 20250 ~ 27000, and 4896 was well off the mark, but reflects 'looking at plot_ly results. I'll give some more thoughts to what is best(n) to close max(df$prop) , where geos might come into play. But I'll likely have to ask on SO.

Using the d estimates and the n+1 property of theta in close_loop = TRUE in circle_xyz, and this warning...circle_xyz(n = seq(20250, 27000, 1), r = sort(df$prop, decreasing = TRUE)[1], z = 12, close_loop = TRUE) Warning message: In seq.default(0, 2 * pi, length.out = n + 1) :   first element used of 'length.out' argument, i.e.  n 20250, nrow(df)20251 returned from circle_xyz and 12 closed, if n were 20249, 12 still open. Agreed?

Sorry, I can't follow you. Can you try and answer my question about how you came to determine n = 4896 in more simple terms? Or, ideally, provide a solution that does not require hardcoding n at all.

Not sure if this is anywhere close to what you'd like to achieve, but I can get 3 separate spirals by adapting the idea of a spring documented here.
split = ~z in the plot_ly() call avoided the connecting lines.
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

create_spiral <- \(x, y, xend, yend, diameter = 1, tension = 0.75, n = 50) {
  length <- sqrt((x - xend)^2 + (y - yend)^2)
  n_revolutions <- length / (diameter * tension)
  n_points <- n * n_revolutions
  radians <- seq(0, n_revolutions * 2 * pi, length.out = n_points)
  x <- seq(x, xend, length.out = n_points)
  y <- seq(y, yend, length.out = n_points)
  data.frame(
    x = cos(radians) * diameter / 2 + x,
    y = sin(radians) * diameter / 2 + y
  )
}

spirals <- map(1:3, \(z) {
  create_spiral(
    x = 4, y = 2, xend = 8, yend = 6,
    diameter = 4, tension = 0.6, n = 50
  ) |>
    mutate(z = z * 5)
}) |>
  bind_rows()

plot_ly(spirals,
  x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, split = ~z,
  type = "scatter3d",
  mode = "lines"
)


Created on 2024-04-22 with reprex v2.1.0

good work but not based on my data

Yes, sorry, failed on that one :(
